# onchange api for many2many in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo-10

In `odoo10` I want to insert value in many2many field `onchnage` depends to
 many2one field:

```
 support_id = fields.Many2one('printshop2.support', 'Print Media', required=False)


 support_ids = fields.Many2many('printshop2.support.line', 'printshop_support_line_rel', 'printshop_id', 'support_id',
                                   string='Print Media')
```

I do this function but it's not work:

```
 def support_onchange(self):
 printshop = self.env['offset.printshop'].browse(self.id)

 allpaper = self.env['printshop2.support.line'].search([('support_id', '=', printshop.support_id.id)])
 self.write({'support_ids':allpaper})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code, Updating many2many is done in a special way, you can not do it like other common fields.

```
allpaper = self.env['printshop2.support.line'].search([('support_id', '=', printshop.support_id.id)])
self.write({'support_ids':[[6, 0, allpaper]]})
```